# My layout does not fit correctly when my information blocks have a long text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get some information in three blocks, each block (except the third) I want to have some right margin.

I already have almost this effect right as you see in my image, but there is something wrong with my CSS and Im not finding what.

Because when my information, for example the address, is too long, instead of the text drop down and keep everything normally, the text falls down but spoils me a bit the rest of my structure, as you can see in the points that I pointed in picture below:

[image]

As you see, my phones info is going down, and my adress is going up.

Do you see what is wrong with my css code? If I dont have long information it is working fine, but when I have longer information, the layout does not fit.

**I have my full example here:** http://jsfiddle.net/1s1jewa3/

My Html:

```
<div id="page-container">
        <h1>Title of the page</h1>
        <img src="" width="700px" height="275px" />
        <div id="info">
            <h2>Informations</h2>
            <ul id="col1">
                <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 000434314</li>
                <li class="last"><i class="fa fa-fax"></i> 000434314 </li>     
            </ul>
            <ul id="col2">
                <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> 8th Street across the NJ Newark Bridge until August 6,</li>
                <li class="last"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Zip code</li>   
            </ul>
            <ul id="col3">
                <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> ouremail@mail.com</li>
                <li class="last"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> ouremail@mail.com</li>       
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="about">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the vertical alignment of the lists:

```
#info ul {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1s1jewa3/1/)**

The default vertical alignment is baseline, which is what you'd get without this change.